# A RenderFlex overflowed by 150 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter

i don't know what iam doing wrong here but is always overflow by 150 pixels to the right , even that iam wraping my card with `Expanded` , also `Flexible` has the same issue

```
asyncorganization.when(
            data: (org) => Scaffold(
                  body: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 1,
                        child: GridView(
                          gridDelegate:
                              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                          children: org.activities
                              .map((e) => Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                    child: Card(
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: TextButton.icon(
                                            onPressed: null,
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.volunteer_activism),
                                            label: Text("${e.title}")),
                                        subtitle: CircleAvatar(
                                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage("${e.picture}"),
                                          radius: 20,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ))
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
            loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
            error: (error, stack) => Center(
                  child: Text("$error"),
                ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set `Flexible` for TextButton's label:

```
ListTile(
                      title: TextButton.icon(
                          onPressed: null,
                          icon: Icon(Icons.volunteer_activism),
                          label: Flexible(child: Text("test"))),
                      subtitle: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(""),
                        radius: 20,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                    )
```